# Inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I am using `Hibernate 5.3.10` as my ORM in the Spring boot based project. Suppose that we have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Parent {
    @EmbeddedId
    private EmbId id;

    public Id getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Id id) { this.id = id; }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "date_time")
})
public class Child {
    @EmbeddedId
    private EmbId id;

    private String name;

    public Id getId() { return this.id; }
    public void setId(Id id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

and the embeddable key as follow:

```
@Embeddable
public class EmbId {
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "date_time")
    private Date dateTime;

    public Long getId() { return this.id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    public Date getDateTime() { return this.dateTime; }
    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) { this.dateTime = dateTime; }
}
```

When I want to polymorphic query on `Child` entity, the JPA faces with ORA-00932 `Inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER` and the following sql have seen in the console:

```
select child0_.id as date_time1_25_0, child0_.date_time as id2_25_0, child0_1_.name as name3_3_0 from my_schema.child child0_ inner join my_schema.parent child0_1_ on child0_.id = child0_1_.date_time and child0_.date_time = child0_1_.id
```

It seems that the equality of IDs is displaced. What happened and what should I do to resolve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I found that adding `referencedColumnName` attribute to `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` could be guide hibernate to use the IDs in the right place.

So, the `Child` class should be as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "date_time")
})
public class Child {
    @EmbeddedId
    private EmbId id;

    private String name;

    public Id getId() { return this.id; }
    public void setId(Id id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```